# Replace part of a string with a pandas column as pattern

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

I would like to use the `.str.replace()` method on a pandas column, but with another pandas column as pattern

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'str1': ['abc','abcd','def'], 'str2': ['b','ab', 'ef']})
```

I want to build a new column `str1_replaced` by replacing in `str1` the `str2` strings by an empty string.

Here's the result I want to get:

```
   str1 str2 str1_replaced
0   abc    b            ac
1  abcd   ab            cd
2   def   ef             d
```

I've tried to do:

```
df['str1_replaced'] = df['str1'].str.replace(df['str2'],"")
```

But I get the following error

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Is there any way to achieve that without using a for loop? I'm thinking of using a lambda function but cannot find out exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `apply`:

```
df['str1_replaced'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['str1'].replace(x['str2'], ''), axis=1)
```

---

```
>>> df
   str1 str2 str1_replaced
0   abc    b            ac
1  abcd   ab            cd
2   def   ef             d
>>>
```

Or try list comprehension:

```
df['str1_replaced'] =[x.replace(y, '') for x, y in zip(df['str1'], df['str2'])]
```

Comment: @fmarm Great! added another solutions as well :)